# Android "is activity running?" BadTokenException on PopupWindow

Tags: java, android, exception, android-context

My current project demands that a *PopupWindow* be displayed with a nested *Spinner* but for some reason, applying this code: (This code essentially instantiates a LinearLayout, creates a Spinner with the elements defined in my array, *spinnersRay*, and places it all on a PopupWindow)

```
    //LINEAR LAYOUT
    editsChangeLinear = new LinearLayout(this);
    editsChangeLinear.setLayoutParams(parentMatches);
    editsChangeLinear.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    editsChangeLinear.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);


            //ARRAYLIST & ADAPTER
    ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(SpinnerIndex i : spinnersRay){
        if(!i.name.replaceAll("\\s","").equals("TUTORIALS"))
        arrayList.add(i.name);
    }
    spinner = new Spinner(this);
    ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
             android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,arrayList);
    spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);


            //ADD VIEW 
    editsChangeLinear.addView(spinner);


    editsChangePopup = new PopupWindow(editsChangeLinear, 
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);


editsChangePopup.setFocusable(true);
    editsChangePopup.setContentView(editsChangeLinear);
            editsChangePopup.showAtLocation(outerScrollView,1,0,0);
```

I am always given the same BadTokenException whenever I click the Spinner, which clear displays the Strings returned from my *i.name* calls which merely access the name elements of my own custom Spinner class called SpinnerIndex which extends Spinner. The Spinner (or at least its very first element) appears to be properly formed, but this exception is thrown whenever I tap it. I do not understand why.

I have tried placing things in seperate Threads or toying with the context but I am quite lost here.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use  , May be it may help you

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                editsChangePopup = new PopupWindow(editsChangeLinear, 
                        LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);


                editsChangePopup.setFocusable(true);
                    editsChangePopup.setContentView(editsChangeLinear);
                            editsChangePopup.showAtLocation(outerScrollView,1,0,0);/ TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks! But unfortunately I've received the same error at the same moment.